# Parse live stream of data Wikipedia

Tags: java, parsing, real-time, influxdb, wikipedia-api

I want to

1. retrieve
2. parse certain content and
3. write to database on a **real-time stream of data** that Wikipedia provides about recent changes here: https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange

I researched and was thinking about Jsoup, however, it looks like Jsoup cannot handle real-time streams. How would I go about doing this in Java?

Ultimately, my objective is to parse and put only the contents I need into an influxDB database while the streams continue to flow.

Answer (score 0):

Open a HTTPS connection, wrap the connection's input stream in an UTF-8 decoding `java.io.BufferedReader`, and read the input line by line in a loop. Then parse the lines according to their respective content. The `id` and `data` lines seem to contain JSON after the prefix, so you can use the JSON library of your choice.
Then write the filtered data to the database.

This is a simplified example using JDK only:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL
    ("https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange").openConnection();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // 1. parse interesting lines according to
    //    their prefix event, id, or data
    // 2. write filtered data to the database
}
```